# Thumbnail no bootstrap 4

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-3, collapse, thumbnail

Alguem pode me dizer por que o "thumbnail" não funciona no bootstrap 4 ?
estou aprendendo melhor o bootstrap, más o curso que peguei ainda ta fazendo com a versão 3.3.7, tive que baixar a mesma pois alguns codigos não estavam funcionando.

```
<main>
    <div>
        <H3 class="text-center"> Novidades </H3>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12 thumbnail text-center">
        <figure>

            <img src="img/camisa-normal.jpg" alt="camisa preta bts" />
            <div>
                <h4> Camisa Preta Bts </h4>
                <p> Camisa do bts com pano de qualidade </p>
            </div>
```

queria saber também por que eu não estou conseguindo dar toggle ( abrir e fechar a barra de menu, sendo que fiz exatamente igual no curso. segue o codigo:

```
<body>
<header>
    <nav>

        <div>
            <a href="#" class="navbar-brand"> Kpopstore </a>
            <button type="button" data-target=".navbar-collapse" data-toggle="collapse"> Menu </button>
        </div>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li> <a href="#">Novidades </a> </li>
                <li> <a href="#">Mais Vendidos </a> </li>
            </ul>
        </div>

    </nav>

</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

No bootstrap 4 panels e thumbnail foram preteridas em função do componente cards.
Mas acho que no seu caso você consegue dar o efeito desejado com a classe `.img-thumbnail`.

Fonte: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/content/images/

Sobre o seu menu, testei aqui e para mim está funcionando.
De repente, posta aí num jsbin o código inteiro pra ver o que está acontecendo.